# ArcMap, Editor and Geodatabase API edit session question

Tags: arcobjects, editing, spatial-database, api, versioning

Say a feature class from a File GDB is added to ArcMap and an editing session on it is in progress. What happens if an add-in launched from the same ArcMap session tries to start an edit session using IWorkSpaceEdit on the same feature class?

What if the feature class is in ArcSDE and versioned?

---

Tested on File GDB. Nothing happened, no crash. The note on IWorkspaceEdit.StartEditing does say "StartEditing cannot be called when a edit session is already active" - it appeared it can?

The note also says "With non-versioned editing always be sure to check the current edit state via IsBeingEdited before called StartEditing or StopEditing.  If the workspace is being edited outside your context, there is no need to call StartEditing" - I'm confused.

Comment: You can read multiple times with a file geodatabase but writing at the same time will not work http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1732&t=303368

Comment: Thanks Mapperz. I understand what you said but I'm asking a  different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know what will happen, I've never used ArcSDE. But you can check the state of the Editor using [IEditor.EditState](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0020000000s9000000) property and use that to stop your addin launching what ever code it was going to do?

Comment: Thanks for the tip Hornbydd. My scenario may require the tool to run while the Editor editing session is in progress though. I am going to do a test on File GDB, but I don't yet have ArcSDE set up so I'm hoping someone can shed some light on that.